# Gems can't be installed as non-root in OS Lion?

Tags: rubygems, file-permissions, osx-lion

I just tried to install my first gem on a clean OS Lion install and got:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.
```

I know I could just use `sudo` but I'd like to know whether it's possible to install gems as non-root.

Comment: No. Unless you change the permissions on that directory, which would generally be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RVM to generate a place to install ruby versions in user space.

https://rvm.io

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash
```